# Scaling part of a PlantUML diagram

Tags: plantuml

Scaling is controlled by the `scale` keyword.  I'm curious if it's possible to scale *part* of a PlantUML diagram somehow or at the very least: scale the font size for part of a diagram.

It doesn't seem like `scale` may be scoped to part of a diagram (and I have not found any examples that suggest that is possible).  Conceivably it might be used in the following manner, but this example scales the entire image:

```
@startuml

package "Some Group" {
  scale 0.5
  HTTP - [First Component]
  [Another Component]
}

node "Other Groups" {
  FTP - [Second Component]
  [First Component] --> FTP
} 

@enduml
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not think currently there is a way to achieve it. From [the source code](https://github.com/plantuml/plantuml/blob/cfa7591c4bc0a44a612348ef6837309ef42d973f/src/net/sourceforge/plantuml/command/CommandScale.java#L68-L83) of the PlantUML `scale` command:

```java
protected CommandExecutionResult executeArg(AbstractPSystem diagram, LineLocation location, RegexResult arg) {
    double scale = Double.parseDouble(arg.get("SCALE", 0));
    if (scale == 0) {
        return CommandExecutionResult.error("Scale cannot be zero");
    }
    if (arg.get("DIV", 0) != null) {
        final double div = Double.parseDouble(arg.get("DIV", 0));
        if (div == 0) {
            return CommandExecutionResult.error("Scale cannot be zero");
        }
        scale /= div;
    }
    diagram.setScale(new ScaleSimple(scale));
    return CommandExecutionResult.ok();
}
```

The location of `scale` is not used, and PlantUML just sets the `scale` of diagram by `diagram.setScale(new ScaleSimple(scale))`.

You can verify this kind of action by:

```
@startuml
    
package "Some Group" {
  scale 0.5
  HTTP - [First Component]
  [Another Component]
}

node "Other Groups" {
  scale 5
  FTP - [Second Component]
  [First Component] --> FTP
}

@enduml
```

The `scale 0.5` is overridden by the `scale 5` command.